# Teradata sql query to assign same rownumbers for group

Tags: sql, teradata

My Input is:-

```
Order,   Item,  SequenceNumber
550,     AA,      1
550,     AA,      2
550,     AA,      3

550,     AA,      1
550,     AA,      2
550,     AA,      3
550,     AA,      4

650,     AA,      1
650,     AA,      2
650,     AA,      3

650,     AA,      1
650,     AA,      2
650,     AA,      3
650,     AA,      4
```

How do I assign the same rownumber to a group of sequence of records. Refer the below example order no.s 550 &650 are having two sets of running sequence numbers. I wanted to assign the same row number for each corresponding order number and set of sequence numbers(1,2,3)

```
Order,   Item,  SequenceNumber
550,     AA,      1
550,     AA,      2
550,     AA,      3

550,     AA,      1
550,     AA,      2
550,     AA,      3
550,     AA,      4

650,     AA,      1
650,     AA,      2
650,     AA,      3

650,     AA,      1
650,     AA,      2
650,     AA,      3
650,     AA,      4
```

Expected result should be with the new row number column populated as below.

```
Order,    Item,  SequenceNumber ,    Rownumber
550,      AA,      1,                     1
550,      AA,      2,                     1
550,      AA,      3,                     1

550,      AA,      1,                     2
550,      AA,      2,                     2
550,      AA,      3,                     2
550,      AA,      4,                     2

650,      AA,      1,                     1
650,      AA,      2,                     1
650,      AA,      3,                     1

650,      AA,      1,                     2
650,      AA,      2,                     2
650,      AA,      3,                     2
650,      AA,      4,                     2
```

solution given below:-

```
SELECT ...
   Sum(flag) -- create the group number
   Over (PARTITION BY Order, Item
                   ORDER BY whatever
                   ROWS Unbounded Preceding)
FROM
 (
   SELECT ...
      -- find the row where a new group starts
      CASE WHEN Min(SequenceNumber) 
                Over (PARTITION BY Order, Item
                      ORDER BY whatever
                      ROWS BETWEEN 1 Preceding AND 1 Preceding) + 1 = SequenceNumber
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
      END AS flag
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
```

Can someone please explain how the code:

> Sum(flag)  Over (PARTITION BY Order, Item ORDER BY whatever ROWS
>   Unbounded Preceding)

actually creates a new group number with the above case.

Step by step explanation would be really appreciated.

Comment: Run the Select in the Derived Table and check the data in the flag column, 0 (SequenceNumber is equal to the previous value plus 1) or 1 (SequenceNumber not equal). Now the outer Select calculates a Cumulative Sum over those 0/1, increasing it whenever the flag is set to 1.

Comment: with sum() function Could you please explain how it automatically increments when flag is 1

Comment: I'm still confused how the outer query cumulative Sum assigns the row number incrementally whenever the flag is 1...

Comment: As the name Cumulative Sum implies, it processes the rows (within a PARTITION) sequentially (defined by ORDER BY), starts with the 1st and adds up all those 0/1 row. Lots of info online (usually not for Teradata, but all DBMSes got (almost) the same syntax), e.g http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2012/how-use-microsoft-sql-server-2012s-window-functions-part-1